# Create Accordion like expansion on cards

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm learning bootstrap5.

I'm attempting to create Accordion, where by when I click on the card it should expand like Accordion and display body text. On clicking the same card again or any other card the current body text of card must close and other card's body text needs to be expanded.

I'm lost on how I can achieve the same.

Kindly note multiple rows of these cards are present. I'm not using any framework like Angular or react.

Code for card:

```
    <section id="interest" class="interest_wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center mb-5">
                    <h2>Interest</h2>
                    <p>Is give may shall likeness made yielding spirit a itself togeth created after sea <br
                            class="d-none d-lg-block">
                        is in beast beginning signs open god you're gathering ithe</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                    <div class="card rounded-0 border-0 p-0">
                        <img decoding="async" src="./images/blog/blog1.webp">
                        <div class="interest_details">
                            <div class="interest_text text-center">
                                <h5 class="text-white mb-0">POLITICS</h5>
                                <div class="border_line"></div>
                                <p class="text-white">Enjoy your social life together</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                    <div class="card rounded-0 border-0 p-0">
                        <img decoding="async" src="./images/blog/blog2.webp">
                        <div class="interest_details">
                            <div class="interest_text text-center">
                                <h5 class="text-white mb-0">FOOD</h5>
                                <div class="border_line"></div>
                                <p class="text-white">Enjoy your social life together</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                    <div class="card rounded-0 border-0 p-0">
                        <img decoding="async" src="./images/blog/blog.webp">
                        <div class="interest_details">
                            <div class="interest_text text-center">
                                <h5 class="text-white mb-0">Social Life</h5>
                                <div class="border_line"></div>
                                <p class="text-white">Enjoy your social life together</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```